# WordPress plugin inner join tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, join

I'm making this plugin for my site where I can generate some coupons for the users. I wrote a plugin and I'm listing all the coupons on a custom admin page.

My custom table looks like so:

Name: wp_rdc
Fields: id, user_id, coupon

Where I'm listing all the coupons I want to join the wp_users table and get the corresponding user_login (username) from the wp_users table to the user_id from the wp_rdc table.

I've tried to write a query like this, but I don't know how to echo out the different variables, I'm new into joining tables.

```
$coupons = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_rdc AS r INNER JOIN wp_users AS u ON u.id = r.user_id ORDER BY user_id DESC');
```

That's how far I am, and now I don't know what to do next. So basically my questions is how to echo out the user_login from the wp_users table?

This is how I echo out my data from the wp_rdc table, where I instead of user_id want to echo out the user_login, because that looks better than just echoing out an ID which doesn't make sense for the end user.

```
$table_row = "";

foreach( $coupons as $coupon ) {
   $table_row .= "<tr>";
   $table_row .= "<td class='rdc-table-data'>" . $coupon->id  . "</td>";
   $table_row .= "<td class='rdc-table-data'>" . $coupon->user_id  . "</td>";
   $table_row .= "<td class='rdc-table-data'>" . $coupon->coupon  . "</td>";
   $table_row .= "</tr>";
}

echo $table_row;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use user_nicename or user_login from the wp_users table:

```
$coupons = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT r.id, r.user_id, r.coupon, u.user_login, u.user_nicename FROM wp_rdc AS r INNER JOIN wp_users AS u ON u.id = r.user_id ORDER BY user_id DESC');

$table_row = "";

foreach( $coupons as $coupon ) {
   $table_row .= "<tr>";
   $table_row .= "<td class='rdc-table-data'>" . $coupon->id  . "</td>";
   $table_row .= "<td class='rdc-table-data'>" . $coupon->user_nicename  . "</td>";
   $table_row .= "<td class='rdc-table-data'>" . $coupon->coupon  . "</td>";
   $table_row .= "</tr>";
}

echo $table_row;
```

Comment: Oh God, I am so stupid..... I shouldn't be allowed to post questions anymore. Of course, thanks a lot, amenadiel!

Comment: Don't worry. $wpdb can be cumbersome at times. After all it was wordpress sorry attempt to make a DB abstraction layer.

Comment: Yeah, it sure can. Thanks again, marked your reply as answered :)